# Exception:- Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql

```
11:33:45,147 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-1) 2014-03-09 11:33:45,147 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-1] CommonController - Logging out...
11:52:21,130 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-1) 2014-03-09 11:52:21,130 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-1] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Session not found, forwarding to /DemoProject/login
11:52:21,131 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-1) 2014-03-09 11:52:21,131 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-1] CommonController - Session isNew: true
11:52:21,131 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-1) 2014-03-09 11:52:21,131 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-1] CommonController - User requesting for login page
11:52:21,828 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-12) 2014-03-09 11:52:21,828 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-12] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Request Param name :: {v=1.1}
11:52:22,491 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 11:52:22,491 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Request Param name :: {v=3.3}
11:52:22,519 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 11:52:22,519 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Request Param name :: {v=1.1}
11:52:33,483 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-17) 2014-03-09 11:52:33,483 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-17] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Request Param name :: {v=20130807}
13:08:11,122 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-28) 2014-03-09 13:08:11,122 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-28] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Session not found, forwarding to /DemoProject/login
13:08:11,151 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-28) 2014-03-09 13:08:11,151 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-28] CommonController - Session isNew: true
13:08:11,152 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-28) 2014-03-09 13:08:11,152 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-28] CommonController - User requesting for login page
16:24:05,247 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:706) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.fillToMin(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:653) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_15]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 371 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 371 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor244.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [:1.6.0_15]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3092)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1299)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2338)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2371)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor22.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [:1.6.0_15]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:378)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2989)
    ... 22 more

16:26:10,094 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 16:26:10,094 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Session not found, forwarding to /DemoProject/login
16:26:10,246 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 16:26:10,246 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] CommonController - Session isNew: false
16:26:10,246 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 16:26:10,246 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] CommonController - User requesting for login page
16:26:12,375 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-12) 2014-03-09 16:26:12,375 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-12] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Session not found, forwarding to /DemoProject/login
16:26:12,377 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-12) 2014-03-09 16:26:12,377 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-12] CommonController - Session isNew: false
16:26:12,377 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-12) 2014-03-09 16:26:12,377 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-12] CommonController - User requesting for login page
16:31:51,457 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:706) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.fillToMin(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:653) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [:1.6.0_15]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 86 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 86 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor244.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [:1.6.0_15]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3092)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1299)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2338)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2371)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor22.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_15]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [:1.6.0_15]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [:1.6.0_15]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:378)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2539)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2989)
    ... 22 more

18:29:50,838 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:50,778 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Session not found, forwarding to /DemoProject/jobs/640473
18:29:51,163 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,163 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Request Param name :: {ref=811, com=2}
18:29:51,231 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,231 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] UserDAO - Query in getRows : SELECT c FROM com.DemoProject.b2b.dto.RecruiterPublishingNetworkStats c  WHERE  bpuin=:bpuin AND jobId=:jobId
18:29:51,686 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,686 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] UserService - Update NumClicksFacebook = -1
18:29:51,686 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,686 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] CommonController - User requesting for getJobDetails page from IP:640473
18:29:51,707 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,707 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] ReformedCriteria - inside transforming criteria value with Criterion :: REQUIRED_DEGREE and criteria Value :: Gen-Bachelors
18:29:51,738 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,720 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] ReformedCriteria - inside transforming criteria value with Criterion :: REQUIRED_AREA_OF_STUDY and criteria Value :: Business/Management/Operations/Marketing/Sales/Operations/Finance/MBA/M.B.A.|Communications|Journalism/Communication/Media/Public Relation|Market/Advertis/Strateg/Sales/Media/Branding/MBA/M.B.A
18:29:51,738 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,738 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] ReformedCriteria - inside transforming criteria value with Criterion :: REQUIRED_WORK_EXP and criteria Value :: 2|10|28|30|44|77
18:29:51,738 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,738 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] ReformedCriteria - inside transforming criteria value with Criterion :: PREFERRED_DEGREE and criteria Value :: Gen-Bachelors
18:29:51,763 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,763 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] ReformedCriteria - inside transforming criteria value with Criterion :: PREFERRED_AREA_OF_STUDY and criteria Value :: Computer/Information/Informatics/i.t./c.s/c.s/i.t/software/web|Economics
18:29:51,823 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,823 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] ManageAccountService - Job Description length :1700
18:29:51,824 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:51,824 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] JobService - Clearing job from session ....
18:29:52,262 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:29:52,261 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Request Param name :: {v=1.1}
18:29:52,262 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-24) 2014-03-09 18:29:52,262 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-24] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Request Param name :: {v=3.3}
18:29:52,305 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-28) 2014-03-09 18:29:52,305 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-28] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Request Param name :: {v=1.1}
18:29:53,832 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-17) 2014-03-09 18:29:53,832 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-17] RequestInitializeInterceptor - Request Param name :: {v=20130807}
18:29:54,589 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:29:54,574 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] ListenerSession - Creating session with session-id = nfNOXIew8oz1drkL5s6h7qd4 ...
18:29:54,600 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:29:54,600 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] EachRequestFilter - Request Param name :: {_tk=DemoProject, random=6400}
18:29:54,604 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:29:54,601 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] EachRequestFilter - ReppifUser request for :: /DemoProjectb2c/checkAuthticationLogin from :: https://secure.DemoProject.com/DemoProject/jobs/640473?ref=811&com=2
18:30:16,048 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:30:16,048 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] EachRequestFilter - Request Param name :: {ref=811, accessToken=, jobId=640473, j_password=Abishe1!, userid=, login_with=email, rdf=apJb, emp=, j_username=abravi@syr.edu, redirectUrl=/c/profile?jobId=640473}
18:30:16,048 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:30:16,048 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] EachRequestFilter - ReppifUser request for :: /DemoProjectb2c/securelogin from :: https://secure.DemoProject.com/DemoProject/jobs/640473?ref=811&com=2
18:30:16,100 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:30:16,100 [ERROR ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] B2CUserDAO - No entity found for query
18:30:16,101 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:30:16,100 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] AuthenticationFailureHandler - Request Param name :: {ref=811, accessToken=, jobId=640473, j_password=Abishe1!, userid=, login_with=email, rdf=apJb, emp=, j_username=abravi@syr.edu, redirectUrl=/c/profile?jobId=640473}
18:30:16,185 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:30:16,185 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] EachRequestFilter - Request Param name :: {login_error=true, username=abravi@syr.edu, loginWith=email}
18:30:16,185 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:30:16,185 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] EachRequestFilter - ReppifUser request for :: /DemoProjectb2c/login from :: https://secure.DemoProject.com/DemoProject/jobs/640473?ref=811&com=2
18:30:16,187 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:30:16,187 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] MiscellaneousController - User requesting for login from :74.79.42.233
18:30:16,229 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-14) 2014-03-09 18:30:16,229 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-14] Class - ZNLTeOSBOy5zITpHGp-uZEE-gI09vsmFIB9xPE8Jwzw
18:30:38,941 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-443-23) 2014-03-09 18:30:38,941 [INFO  ][http--0.0.0.0-443-23] EachRequestFilter - ReppifUser request for :: /DemoProjectb2c/ from :: https://secure.DemoProject.com/DemoProjectb2c/login?login_error=true&username=abravi@syr.edu&loginWith=email
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Actually. I got this Exception on Server log and not able to fix.